# Creating Time-series collection in MongoDB 5.0.1 throws error Time-series collection is not enabled

Tags: mongodb, time-series

I have MongoDB deployed in AWS EC2, we just upgraded it to 5.0.1. Now while creating a new Time-Series collection it throws error `MongoServerError: Time-series collection is not enabled`. Do I need to enable it manually in config file? If yes, then what is the config parameter?

Comment: How did you create the collection? What do you get from `db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )`?

Comment: did you do `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "5.0" } )` during the upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

You have to use command below during the upgrade:

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "5.0" } )
```